# Make constructor params implicitly available in class body

Tags: scala, implicit

I would like to make the explicit constructor parameters of my class implicitly available in the class body.

I can mark the second and subsequent parameters as "`implicit val`", which works:

```
scala> class Foo(x: Int, implicit val y: String) {
     |   println(implicitly[String])
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo(1,"hello")
hello
```

but if I mark the first parameter as `implicit`, then Scala thinks I am marking the whole argument list as an implicit argument list, and adds an empty first argument list:

```
scala> class Bar(implicit val x: Int, y: String) {
     |   println(implicitly[Int])
     | }
defined class Bar

scala> new Bar(1,"hello")
<console>:9: error: too many arguments for constructor Bar: ()(implicit x: Int, implicit y: String)Bar
              new Bar(1,"hello")
              ^
```

Is there any way to make the first explicit constructor argument explicitly in scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it implicitly available by using an `implicit def` inside:

```
class Foo(val x: Int, implicit val y: String) {
    implicit def ix = x
}
```

which is hideously verbose, but it doesn't look like there is another way to get around the ambiguity between `implicit` marking a parameter list implicit and `implicit val` marking an implicit field.

Comment: Though they share the keyword `implicit`, an `implicit def` is a completely different animal than an `implicit val`. The `implicit def` is a conversion to be used when an expression doesn't type check as written ('cause the referenced value member does not appear in the actual type to which it's applied). The `implicit val` makes available a value that can be automatically passed to a method or constructor that takes a type-compatible `implicit` formal parameter.

Comment: @RandallSchulz That is incorrect. An `implicit def` that doesn't take parameters acts the same as an `implicit val`. An `implicit def` that takes one parameter will act as an implicit conversion.

Comment: @RandallSchulz And on a deeper level, an implicit conversion is really just a kind of implicit, not a different animal at all. For example, if you mark a `Map` as implicit, because it subtypes `A => B`, you have made available an implicit conversion.

Comment: Ah, indeed. And I'll note for completeness sake that the 2.11 compiler does not complain at all about an `implicit def` with more than one argument. As for the notion that a one-argument `implicit def` and an `implicit val` or zero-argument `implicit def` are essentially the same thing, I don't agree since what triggers the compiler to search for one to use is entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

I would have said, Add other local modifiers:

```
scala> class Foo(@deprecated("","") private implicit val x: Int, val y: String) { println(implicitly[Int]) }
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo(42, "hi")
<console>:9: error: too many arguments for constructor Foo: ()(implicit x: Int, y: String)Foo
              new Foo(42, "hi")
              ^
```

Syntactically, that's different from the leading `implicit` keyword, so maybe it's a parser bug, or maybe it does distinguish an implicit param list from a leading param marked locally-implicit but doesn't use the difference.

Comment: Thanks; it does look like the Scala compiler ought to be able to tell the difference. As you point out though, it still fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo(x: Int, y: String) {
  implicit val xImp = x

  println(implicitly[Int])
}
```

Actually I would do it similarly for the first case too. This is a situation where I think that the lot more understandable code is worth a bit more verbosity:

```
class Foo(x: Int, y: String) {
  implicit val yImp = y

  println(implicitly[String])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree. I don't think there's any way to do what I want. I've accepted 'wingedsubmariner's answer as it is essentially the same as yours and they got there seconds before you.